# Calling SQL Substr Function after the Where Clause is used

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL query as follows:

```
select telephone from tableA where telephone !="";
```

now when the above would work as it would do the command properly. However, as in my area telephones are required to be 10 digits long and sometimes the data is missing the leading '0', I have changed the sqlQuery to as follows:

```
select substr('0000000000'||telephone,-10,10) from tableA where telephone != "";
```

The above query would not work with the "where" clause as all empty fields would now contain '0000000000'.

Is there a way to check first if the telephone is empty and then do the above substr function?

The above example is just a simple one so I can just change where telephone != '0000000000' but I have other more complex queries that I would like to use and I do not want to change the where clause.

Comment: The `substr` doesn't affect the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `WHERE` happens first and operates on the original table data. You're confusing `WHERE` with `HAVING`, which operates on the selected results.

Comment: Did you try it and run into the problem you describe?

Comment: why the second parameter in your substr is `-10`? Didn't you want `substr('0000000000'||telephone,1,10)` instead?

Comment: @cha, no, you need the _last_ ten characters of the field after it's been prefixed. That's what gives you zero-padding on the left. Your variant would _always_ give you `0000000000`.

Answer (score 1):

> The above query would not work with the "where" clause as all empty fields would now contain '0000000000'.

No, not so. The fact that you have `where telephone != ""` in your query means that rows with empty fields are not actually included in the results.

The `select` will only extract rows that meet the conditions specified in the `where` clause, *then* it will apply any transformations to the rows that have been extracted.

> Is there a way to check first if the telephone is empty and then do the above substr function?

Yes, there is. You're doing it. Problem solved :-)